# exec() throws Errno::EBADF with ruby 2.1.1

Tags: ruby, osx-mavericks, rbenv

The code below works fine in Ruby 1.9.3 but throws a `Bad file descriptor` exception with Ruby 2.1.1 (even with `close_on_exec` set to false).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

if ARGV.empty?
    f = open("/dev/null")
    f.close_on_exec = false if respond_to?(:close_on_exec=)
else
    f = IO.for_fd(ARGV[0].to_i)
    exit
end

exec "./client.rb", f.fileno.to_s
```

Output:

```
./client.rb:7:in `for_fd': Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)
from ./client.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

Has anything else, besides `close_on_exec`, changed that I'm missing?

Comment: What argument are you passing to the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing `:close_others => false` as options in addition to setting `close_on_exec = false` solves it. E.g.

```
exec "./client.rb", f.fileno.to_s, :close_others => false
```